# How to tell the browser to shrink the table cell at the right place when width is narrow

Tags: html, css

Confusing title, I know. If anyone has a suggestion that is more suitable please tell me.

I have a table which has a very long content in the second column and that makes the content of the last column overflow even though there is enough space in the second column because content gets wrapped.
How do I tell the browser to shrink the space of the second column instead of overflowing on the last one?
I feel like this has something to do with padding.

Here is my table and as you can see the right column is overflowing.
[image: Table with highlight on the last column]
**Now I want the browser to remove space from the right of the second column** (with the new place thanks to the word-wrap) **first** (dashed red), **then from the padding** (dashed blue) until suppressing the padding totally **and after that** not overflowing text but **blocking the table width and not shrinking the table any more** (like min-width does).
There is a lot of blank space that can be removed before overflowing.
[image: Table with highlight on the second column]
I want the table to be dynamic, and I need exactly the default behaviour except that it doesn't seem to be optimized for my specific use case.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px 5%;
}

td:first-child,
th:first-child {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>Header 2</th>
    <th>Header 3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>...\ErrorHandlerMiddleware->App\Application\Middleware\{closure}(...)</td>
    <td>...\HelloAction.php:42</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>...\MiddlewareDispatcher.php:128$25a->handle(...)</td>
    <td>...\ErrorHandlerMiddleware.php:91</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either apply `word-wrap: break-word;` to the td element or set a smaller, fixed `padding`

See the snippet below:

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td:first-child,
th:first-child {
  padding: 10px;
}

td {
word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>Header 2</th>
    <th>Header 3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>...\ErrorHandlerMiddleware->App\Application\Middleware\{closure}(...)</td>
    <td>...\HelloAction.php:42</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>...\MiddlewareDispatcher.php:128$25a->handle(...)</td>
    <td>...\ErrorHandlerMiddleware.php:91</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Is there no way to do it without wrapping the content of the last column? This (https://i.imgur.com/wjGRso6.png) is significantly impacting the readability. I would much more like the browser to remove blank space

Comment: The additional padding is coming from this CSS `td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px 5%;
}`  - I removed it in the updated snippet above. Does that solve the issue?

Comment: I liked the padding because when there is enough space (full screen) the contents has a bit of space between them. And with the percentage it was cool because it was dynamic so more padding when more space. 
But now I removed the padding and even though it doesn't look exactly like I wanted, I can live with it and the text is no longer overlapping. Thank you!

Comment: No problem, happy to help!